# How to assign a value to an array using the ngModel in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, angular-ngmodel

I'm creating the following form :

[image]

I want to add another Input, this is my model.ts:

```
export class ScheduleConfig {
    id: number;
    hourOfSave: string;
    numDaysInDB: number;
}

export class EmailConfig {
    id: number;
    succesEmail: string;
    failureEmail: string;
}

export class DBconnection {
    id: number;
    serverType: string;
    serverName: string;
    port: string;
    authType: string;
    userName: string;
    password: string;
    dbName: string;
    folderName: string;
    scheduleConfig: ScheduleConfig[];
    emailConfig: EmailConfig[];
}
```

And this is component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { MessageService, SelectItem } from 'primeng/api';
import { DBconnection, EmailConfig } from 'src/app/models/db-connection';
import { DbConnectionService } from 'src/app/services/db-connection.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-db-connections',
  templateUrl: './db-connections.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./db-connections.component.css']
})
export class DbConnectionsComponent implements OnInit {
  dbConnectionForm: FormGroup;
  dbConn = new DBconnection();
  dbConns: DBconnection[] = [];
  submitted: boolean;
  OldValueConn: DBconnection;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private messageService: MessageService,
    private dbConnService: DbConnectionService
  ) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.dbConns = await this.dbConnService.getAllConnDB().toPromise();
    // console.log('cons:', this.dbConns);
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.dbConn.id) {
      this.dbConnService.getConnDB(this.dbConn.id).subscribe(res => {
        this.OldValueConn = res;
        this.dbConnService.updateConnDB(this.dbConn).subscribe(() => {
          this.messageService.add({
            severity: 'info',
            summary: 'Success',
            detail: `BD ${this.dbConn.dbName} mise à jour!`,
            sticky: false
          });
        });
      });
    } else {
      this.dbConnService.addConnDB(this.dbConn).subscribe(async result => {
        this.messageService.add({
          severity: 'info',
          summary: 'Success',
          detail: `BD ${result.dbName} créee`,
          sticky: false
        });
        this.dbConns = await this.dbConnService.getAllConnDB().toPromise();
      });
    }
  }

  onDelete(id: number) {
    this.dbConnService.deleteConnDB(id).subscribe(async result => {
      this.messageService.add({
        severity: 'info',
        summary: 'Success',
        detail: `BD ${result.dbName} supprimé`,
        sticky: true
      });
      this.dbConns = await this.dbConnService.getAllConnDB().toPromise();
    });
  }

  SelectBD(SelectedDbConn) {
    this.dbConn = SelectedDbConn;
  }
}
```

When I add the pInputText, so I can get the emailSucces like this in the .html:

```
<div class="ui-grid-row">
            <div class="ui-grid-col-2" style="width: 150px;">
              Email de succes *:
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-col-6">
              <input
                pInputText
                type="text"
                id="succesMail"
                name="succesMail"
                required="required"
                placeholder="Requis"
                #succesMail="ngModel"
                [(ngModel)]="dbConn.emailConfig[0].succesEmail"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-col-4">
              <p-message
                severity="error"
                [text]="
                succesMail.errors.required
                    ? 'L\'email de succes est requis'
                    : ''
                "
                *ngIf="!succesMail.valid && succesMail.dirty"
              ></p-message>
            </div>
          </div>
```

It gives me this error in the console:

[image]

How can I pass a value to the first element of the Array (EmailConfig[])?
I done some researches and I think that it's caused by the ngModel that is trying to read from an undefiened object.
I have tried to do this: `[(ngModel)]="dbConn.emailConfig[0]?.succesEmail` par it doesn't work :/

Any help would be appreciated, thank you! :)

EDIT:

Here is what I guet from the database, and I display it on a table (my model is working fine I guess):

[image]

And when I can console.log I get this:

[image]

Comment: can you add 'dbconn' object here?

Comment: It's on the component.ts : `dbConn = new DBconnection();`

Comment: As based on your error message. In your dbConn doesn't have emailConfig object in it.
Kindly check it

Comment: use null safe operator, or elvis operator
`dbConn?.emailConfig[0].succesEmail`

Comment: I have tried it, same error :(

Comment: the elvis operator can not be used in a [(ngModel)], the problem is that emailConfig should be an array, this array should be at least an array with one object (if dbConn. emailConfig is null or is not an array of object you can not. check the value and try use *ngIf="dbConn" to avoid initial errors

Comment: Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: In your ts file when SelectBD called?

If it called can you add console.log(this.dbConn)

Here your got the dbConn object.

Comment: Yes it does I have tested that, I'm displaying the data in a table, I'll add it right now, give a second.

Answer (score 0):

So I stayed awake all night to fix it, here is the solution:
in my mode.ts I had to initialize the array like this : `emailConfig: EmailConfig[]=[];`
And in the `<div>` in component.html I had to loop over with `*ngFor` like this:

```
<div class="ui-grid-col-2" style="width: 150px;">
              Email de succes *:
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-col-6" *ngFor="let email of dbConn.emailConfig">
              <input
                pInputText
                type="text"
                id="succesMail{{email}}"
                name="succesMail"
                required="required"
                placeholder="Requis"
                #succesMail="ngModel"
                [(ngModel)]="email.succesEmail"
              />
            </div>
```

Now it's not giving any error :D, thanks everyone for sharing your knowledge and helping :)